# Frame Dynamic sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I'm planning on making a generic code for selecting columns from a table using a control table.

My control Table:

```
SEQ Table_Name  Column_name
1   X   X1
1   X   X2
1   X   X3
2   Y   Y1
2   Y   Y2
2   Y   Y3
2   Y   Y4
3   Z   Z1
3   Z   Z2
```

Need help on achieving one like below sample:

Sample Dynamic query:

```
Select Y1,Y2,Y3,Y4 from Y;
```

If I want to make the table name in control table as dynamic like below.

```
Select X1,x2,X3 from x
Union
Select y1,y2,y3,y4 from y
Union
Select z1,z2 from z.
```

If I add more tables it should make union queries

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LISTAGG` with group by `seq, table_name`.

```
 SELECT 'select '
       ||Listagg(column_name, ',')
           within GROUP ( ORDER BY seq )
       ||' FROM '
       || table_name query
FROM   control_table
GROUP  BY seq,
          table_name;
```

**O/p:**

```
QUERY
-----
select X1,X2,X3 FROM X
select Y1,Y2,Y3,Y4 FROM Y
select Z1,Z2 FROM Z
```

**EDIT:**

> If I want to make the table name in control table as dynamic like
>   below, please suggest.

You can use another `LISTAGG`. But i don't recommend this as the query should not exceed 4000 characters. Try to write a `PL/SQL` procedure to append it. I have given you the idea?

```
WITH tabs
     AS (SELECT 'select '
                ||Listagg(column_name, ',')
                    within GROUP ( ORDER BY seq )
                ||' FROM '
                || table_name query
         FROM   control_table
         GROUP  BY seq,
                   table_name)
SELECT Listagg(query, ' UNION ')
         within GROUP ( ORDER BY ROWNUM ) final_query
FROM   tabs;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7c115/10

Comment: Thanks, but If I want to make the table name in control table as dynamic like below, please suggest.
Select X1,x2,X3 from x
Union
Select y1,y2,y3,y4 from y
Union
Select z1,z2 from z.
If I add more tables it should make union queries

Comment: @Amjath : Edited check now. I feel there are better approaches to handle than what you are trying to do. Your database design especially.

Comment: You are right, listagg handles only 4000 chars we end up in trouble once because of it in production. I was thinking of making everything in stored proc. But looking for any other simplified query if any

Comment: The tables and columns are going to be huge. I might have to add flags to switch on and off on some columns and tables. So 4000 chars I don't wanna take the risk

Comment: Ok.Then write a generic function for concatenation.  Refer from  https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques  to start.